# Struts 2 validate method not working without XML

Tags: java, jsp, validation, struts2, ognl

I'm using Struts 2 for developing a web application. I have action class implementing `ActionSupport`. My problem is that when I enter some text error messages are not getting cleared as well as form is also not getting submitted.

Here's what I have:

**`CustomerAction.java`:**

```
public class CustomerAction extends ActionSupport
    {
    private Customer customer = new Customer();
    
    private String customerName;
    
    private String emailID;
    
    public String getCustomerName() {
            return customerName;
        }
    
        public void setCustomerName(String customerName) {
            this.customerName = customerName;
        }
    public Customer getCustomer() {
            return customer;
        }
    
        /**
         * @param customer
         */
        public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
            this.customer = customer;
        }
    
    public String getEmailID() {
            return emailID;
        }
    
        public void setEmailID(String emailID) {
            this.emailID = emailID;
        }
    
    public void validate()
        {
            
            if (customerName == null)
            {
                
                addFieldError("customer.customerName","Required");
                
            }
    
            if (emailID == null || emailID.trim().equals(""))
            {
                addFieldError("customer.emailID","Email is Required");
                }

        }
```

**`Struts.xml`:**

```
    <action name="addCustomer" class="com.yell.hibu.action.CustomerAction" method="execute">
    <interceptor-ref name="params">
    
    <param name="excludeParams">dojo\..*,^struts\..*</param>
    
    </interceptor-ref>
    
    <interceptor-ref name="validation">
    
    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param></interceptor-ref>
    
    <interceptor-ref name="workflow">
    
    <param name="excludeMethods">input,back,cancel,browse</param>
    
   </interceptor-ref>
  <result name="input">/registration.jsp</result>
 <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
</action>
</package>
</struts>
```

**`regisration.jsp`:**

```
    <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
    
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
   

 
<html>
<head>

 <title>Customer Registration Form</title>
  <s:head/>
 </head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>
    <center>
<table width="450" align="center">
            <tr>
<td align="center" height="40"><font
style="color: #003300; font-family: fantasy !important;"><strong
                        style="color: #003300 !important;">Registration Form</strong></font></td></tr>

<tr>
<td width="1000" align="center"><br> <font color="#003300"><s:actionerror/>
<s:form action="addCustomer" id="register-form" method="post" theme="xhtml" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        
<s:textfield name="customer.customerID" label="Customer ID" size="15"  />
<s:textfield name="customer.customerName" label="Customer Name:" maxlength="10"/>
</s:form>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: You are validating `customerName` but submitting to `customer.customerName`.

Comment: ok..Can you please suggest me some changes.

Comment: What is ok? What do you want to validate?

Comment: As a side note, I'd be very cautious about removing most of the interceptors from your action like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the form submitted you need to pass the `validate` method not adding there errors in it. if you adding errors or errors are added via xml validation then by default framework will return the `input` result. it is `/registration.jsp` in your action. The `execute` method not executed then. You get that errors added because the action fields are not initialized. In the JSP you are referencing object `customer` and using OGNL notation the values would be set by the `params` interceptor inside it. So, to validate this values you should write

```
public void validate() {
 if (customer.getCustomerName() == null || customer.getCustomerName().trim().equals("")) {
   addFieldError("customer.customerName", "Required");
 }
}
```

If you don't not use the `customer` object in the JSP then you should use OGNL notation for the field names that references the action attributes.

then validate

```
public void validate() {
 if (customerName == null || customerName.trim().equals("")) {
   addFieldError("customerName", "Required");
 }
 // the same for email ID
}
```

thought you've got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
private String customerName;

private String emailID;
```

from Action (along with getters and setters), and ensure that the same fields (along with CustomerID) are inside `Customer` object with getters and setters.

Then, check out why you are posting `CustomerID` and `CustomerName` from page, but checking `EmailID` and `CustomerName` in the Action.

Add `EmailID` in the JSP, or remove it from the validation method.